# Is this appropriate to show these sets are not separated?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following two sets:

$A = \{{\frac{n}{n+1},\  n = 1,2,3..}\}$

$B = \{\frac{-n+2}{n+1},\  n = 0,1,2..\}$

I know to show separation: $\bar A \  \cap \  B = \emptyset$ and $\bar B \  \cap \  A = \emptyset$, where $\bar X$ is the closure of $X$. The closure of a set is defined as the union of that set and its limit points. $A$ has a limit point of $1$, so therefore $\bar A = [\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4}...1) \cup {1}$. $B$ has a limit point of $-1$, so $\bar B = [2,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{-1}{4}...-1) \cup -1$. $\frac{1}{2} \in \bar A \cap B$, therefore $\bar A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, so $A$ and $B$ are not separated.

Comment: Yes if $A\cap B\not=\emptyset$ then they cannot be separated.  But that does seem too simple, perhaps there's a typo or something?

Comment: These sets aren't even disjoint. How could they be separated?

Comment: @GregoryGrant There is no typo. It was just to make sure I did it properly or had the definition in check.

Comment: @JohnYates Well your proof is correct but actually it is not very elegant becuase there's no reason to calculate the limit points, just say that $1/2\in A\cap B$ and QED.  You never want to work harder than necessary.

Comment: If the 1/2 was not there, your proof would be on the right track, but have a gap: you know that 1 is a limit point of A, but you must also show it doesn't have any other limit points that might be contained in B.